# C++ templates partial specialization with classes

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I am trying C++ partial template specialization with classes. The question is more about syntax than semantics. Actually I want to have to have something as follow:

```
int main()
{
   ...
   Reduce<int, float> r(new int, new float);
   Reduce<int> r2(new int); // partial template specialization?
   ...
}
```

For achieving above I tried:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class Reduce {
  public:
    Reduce(T *t, U *u) { }
};

template <typename T>
class Reduce<T,T> {
  public:
    Reduce(T *t) { }
};
```

With above code, I cannot use following statement:

```
Reduce<int> r2(new int); // error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
```

Still I have to do:

```
Reduce<int, int> r2(new int);
```

Can somebody explain:
(1) how could I achieve my desired syntax (if possible) 
(2) if not possible, why? (i.e. technical issues)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify a default type for second template type:

```
template <typename T, typename U = int>
class Reduce {
  public:
    Reduce(T *t, U *u) { }
};
```

or to default to same as first template type:

```
template <typename T, typename U = T>
class Reduce {
  public:
    Reduce(T *t, U *u) { }
};
```

See http://ideone.com/5RcEG for example.

Comment: @Griwes, I am not following you? Why would the second parameter require a default value: `Reduce<char, float> r(new char, new float);` or `Reduce <char> r(new char);` ?? If the two types are the same, then there is no second parameter.

Comment: @Griwes, was it your downvote? If not, could downvoter please explain?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you ultimatly want, this may or may not be the solution, but at least it compiles:

```
template <typename... T>
class Reduce;

template <typename T, typename U>
class Reduce<T,U> {
  public:
    Reduce(T *t, U *u) { }
};

template <typename T>
class Reduce<T> {
  public:
    Reduce(T *t) { }
};

int main()
{
   Reduce<int, float> r(new int, new float);
   Reduce<int> r2(new int); // partial template specialization?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your template declaration

```
template <typename T>
class Reduce<T,T> {
  public:
    Reduce(T *t) { }
};
```

you can see that you need to supply 2 template arguments to Reduce. So change your usage too

```
Reduce<int,int> r2(new int)
```